# How to add an optional string or end the string with Regex?

Tags: regex

I want to get all Strings that start with a "$" sign followed by an integer or have exactly two digits after the decimal point.
e.g. $7.26 and $48.49 and $17
but not $.49 and $192.9

That's my regular expression so far: `^[$]\d+**[.][0-9][0-9]**`

I want the marked part to be optional or the string has to end.

Also, how could I use `[0-9]{2}` instead of `[0-9][0-9]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern: `^\$\d+(?:\.\d{2})?$`

See Regex [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LuvTNF/1)

**Explanation**

- `^`: Start of the string.
- `\$`: Match with the character `$`.
- `\d+`: Match with one or more digits between 0-9.
- `(?:`: Start of the non-captured group.
- `\.`: Match with the dot character.
- `\d{2}`: Match exactly two digits.
- `)`: End of the group.
- `?`: Make everything in the group optional.
- `$`: End of the string.

Note: the `$` and `.` character in regex means respectively end of the string and everything, so if we want to capture exactly the `$` character (not the end of the string) we should escape those characters.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to escape characters, which are used as part of syntax of RegEx. Try used backslash
**^$\d+(?:.[0-9][0-9])?$**
Or used example in first answer - with {2} - it's more correct